# Read a rest of the string by a substring

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this :

```
string mystring = "No : 123 - Date : 07/06/2009 - Explanation : Some explanation text"
```

I want to get **Some explanation text** from this string. How can I code get the rest of the string after **Explanation :**  in C#? Or is there a better way to get that substring? Thanks.

Comment: then, why you also suggest this kind of recommendation like other's answers

Comment: there could be multiple ways to do this, first you need to do generalization before doing any implementation

Comment: I would go for something like `string.IndexOf(" - Explanation : ")` together with a `string.Substring()`.

Comment: @UweKeim You also recommend the same like others post. But, still you down vote the other's post as well. Now. OP's confused....! (((:

Comment: @UweKeim You just made confused OP. :((((

Comment: @UweKeim Don't let it simply down vote other's post. You just make smart answer for your hint as well and post that answer to make helpful to OP.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IodBGF

Comment: @UweKeim you just post it as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend a Regex approach here, it would remove the issues from other posts where the `:`character could be included in the explanation string.

This example would solve the issue as long the "Explanation :" tag is always at the end of the string and the "Explanation :" text can not appear inside the *Some explanation text*.

```
var mystring = "No : 123 - Date : 07/06/2009 - Explanation : Some explanation text"
var regex = new Regex("(.*)Explanation :(.*)");
var match = regex.Match(mystring);

if (match.Success)
{
   var explanation =  match.Groups[match.Groups.Count - 1].Value;
}
```

Comment: its not working.. it returns empty string! :(((

Comment: Pardon me, you have to use `match.Groups.Count - 1` as the index. I updated the answer

Comment: Works! https://dotnetfiddle.net/99g939 (although I would prefer a faster, non-regex version here, since I do see no benefits. E.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/IodBGF)

Comment: Great! It works!! you awesome :)

Comment: It works perfectly :))))

Answer (score 3):

```
string mystring = "No : 123 - Date : 07/06/2009 - Explanation : Some explanation text";
string explSection = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf("Explanation :"));
string explText = string.Join("",explSection.Split(':').Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Above code will give you required text.

Comment: What if `Some explanation text` contains a `:`? (Hint: it is splitted, too).

Comment: @UweKeim modified my answer to cover your case.

Comment: [Works better now](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbovmR). Do you really need the `Substring` and `IndexOf` twice? [How about this one](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IodBGF)?

Comment: @UweKeim edited my answer. now using Substring and IndexOf only once

Answer (score -1):

```
String mystring = "No : 123 - Date : 07/06/2009 - Explanation : Some explanation text";
string[] substrngs = mystring.Split(':');
string desiredString = substrngs[substrngs.Count - 1];
```

String.Split(char delim) will return a string[] with all strings found by splitting by your delimiter, ':' .
Then use the Count property of the string[] to find how many strings were found by Split() and get last element based on your parse desires.

Comment: What if `Some explanation text` contains a `:`? (Hint: it is splitted, too).

Comment: Based in his format it is what I can derive.  Can only answer with given situation.  Parsing can be done infinite amount of times; the way to parse an input depends on the input's format and desires from the input.

Comment: Considering the 1 example string provided by the poster and choosing the `Split`method as to get the desired substring, it might be better to Split by ` - ` and then search for the part which starts with "Explanation :". However this fails again if the "Explanation :" part contains the `-` character. In general, if possible a better delimiter for the data would be best and make a better `Split` option (IMO)